# Hide x-axis labels in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have used bar plot to display the following dataframe:

```
   city   pred  actual
9     j  10.05   12.68
0     a   9.72    9.56
6     g   8.29    9.11
2     c   8.22    8.49
3     d   7.88    7.92
8     i   7.04    7.35
5     f   6.06    6.33
1     b   5.94    6.00
7     h   5.52    5.72
4     e   5.37    5.62
10    k   6.04    5.50
```

Code to plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 7)

colors = ['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'g']
df = df.sort_values(by=['actual'], ascending=False)
ax = df.plot(x="city", y=["actual", "pred"], kind="bar", color = colors, alpha=0.8)
plt.legend(["actual", "pred"], fontsize=15)
plt.gca().set_xticklabels(df['city'])
plt.suptitle("pred vs actual", fontsize=18)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(np.round(p.get_height(),decimals=2), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2., \
                         p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]
What I'm trying try to do is to hide unwanted **city** text labels from x axis. My expected output will like this:

[image]

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is the only one I find works:

```
ax.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
```

If you have other solutions, welcome to share.